# Using sumlists with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Brand new to python and I have to make a list that prompts the user to tell the size of the list, then to list the numbers in the list. Then it needs to sum the list this is what I have so far. I get the error 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I dont know what I am doing wrong I must be crazy tired.

```
def two():
    n = str(input("What is the size of the list?"))
    to_be_summed = [int(input("What are the numbers?")) for x in range(n)]
    sum(to_be_summed)
two()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("What is the size of the list?"))
```

`range` needs an int ... if the user does not type an integer you will still get an error... if you want to force the user to provide an integer its often helpful to write a helper function

```
  def get_int(prompt="Enter A Number:"):
      while 1:
          try: return int(input(prompt))
          except: print("sorry invalid input!")
```

then you can simply say

```
n = get_int("What is the size of the list?")
```

Comment: I added one, I still get the same error? maybe I am adding it the wrong way?

Comment: you added one what? ... you shouldnt get the same error if you replace your line with the one i posted here

Comment: Sorry I mistyped I get another error I see where I messed up, the other error im getting is invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: that means you gave it a string that it cannot convert to an integer

Comment: to_be_summed = [int(input("What are the numbers?")) for x in range(n)] I am assuming its this line

Comment: no its what you typed in response to "What are the numbers" ... as it expects one number and then you press enter... I assume you are typing the whole list in at once ... just type one number each time it asks...

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You are summing the list, you're just not doing anything with the result. :-)

```
n = int(input('How many numbers are in the list? '))
alist = [int(input('Enter the number: ')) for _ in range(n)]
print('Sum of the numbers is', sum(alist))
```